# Run "future" one by one

Tags: flutter

now i have this script

```
  Future<List<HotProducts>> _loadHotProducts;
  Future<List<NewProducts>> _loadNewProducts;
  Future<List<Promotion>> _loadPromotions;
  Future<List<LatestSoldItem>> _loadLatestSoldItem;
    setState(() {
              userId = result;
              _loadHotProducts = HotProductsApiClient().fetchHotProducts(http.Client(), userId);
              _loadNewProducts = NewProductApiClient().fetchNewProducts(http.Client(), userId);
              _loadPromotions = PromotionApiClient().fetchPromotion(http.Client());
              _loadLatestSoldItem = LatestSoldApiClient().fetchProducts(http.Client(), userId);
            });
```

all my script above is about calling data from my server. Now, i want to run it one by one. So, i'm trying this way

```
_loadHotProducts = HotProductsApiClient().fetchHotProducts(http.Client(), userId).then((_){
            _loadNewProducts = NewProductApiClient().fetchNewProducts(http.Client(), userId);
          });
```

I get this errors

```
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

How can i fix it ? or is there any better way ?

Comment: please also add your methods and build method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encounter is inside your fetch function 
you have to `await` all your `http` and `future` job 
You can copy paste run correct and problem code in DartPad 
The following demo have 3 layer function call, you check effect with or without `await` 
When you doubt, just print message and you will see execution sequence 
 
The following correct and problem is provided as below

full code correct

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';


Future<String> fetchHotProductsLongJob() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
    print('fetchHotProductsLongJob then');
  });
  print("fetchHotProductsLongJob done");
  return "abc";

}

Future<String> fetchHotProducts() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7), () {
    print("fetchHotProducts then");
  });
  await fetchHotProductsLongJob();
  print("fetchHotProducts done");
  return "abc";

}

Future<String> fetchNewProductsLongJob() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
    print('fetchNewProductsLongJob then');
  });
  print("fetchNewProductsLongJob done");
  return "abc";

}

Future<String> fetchNewProducts() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () async{
    print("fetchNewProducts then");
    await fetchNewProductsLongJob();
  });
  print("fetchNewProducts done");
  return "abc";

}



void main()  async{
  print("fetchHotProducts job start");
  var Job1 = await fetchHotProducts();  
  print("fetchHotProducts job done");

  print("fetchNewProducts job start");
  var Job2 = await fetchNewProducts();
  print("fetchNewProducts job done");  

}
```

correct output

```
fetchHotProducts job start
fetchHotProducts then
fetchHotProductsLongJob then
fetchHotProductsLongJob done
fetchHotProducts done
fetchHotProducts job done
fetchNewProducts job start
fetchNewProducts then
fetchNewProductsLongJob then
fetchNewProductsLongJob done
fetchNewProducts done
fetchNewProducts job done
```

correct demo
[image]

problem code after remove some await

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';


Future<String> fetchHotProductsLongJob() async {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
    print('fetchHotProductsLongJob then');
  });
  print("fetchHotProductsLongJob done");
  return "abc";

}

Future<String> fetchHotProducts() async {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7), () {
    print("fetchHotProducts then");
  });
  fetchHotProductsLongJob();
  print("fetchHotProducts done");
  return "abc";

}

Future<String> fetchNewProductsLongJob() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
    print('fetchNewProductsLongJob then');
  });
  print("fetchNewProductsLongJob done");
  return "abc";

}

Future<String> fetchNewProducts() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () async{
    print("fetchNewProducts then");
    await fetchNewProductsLongJob();
  });
  print("fetchNewProducts done");
  return "abc";

}



void main()  async{
  print("fetchHotProducts job start");
  var Job1 = await fetchHotProducts();  
  print("fetchHotProducts job done");

  print("fetchNewProducts job start");
  var Job2 = await fetchNewProducts();
  print("fetchNewProducts job done");  

}
```

problem code output
you can see fetchHotProducts job still not finish

```
fetchHotProducts job start
fetchHotProductsLongJob done
fetchHotProducts done
fetchHotProducts job done
fetchNewProducts job start
fetchNewProducts then
    fetchHotProducts then
    fetchHotProductsLongJob then
fetchNewProductsLongJob then
fetchNewProductsLongJob done
fetchNewProducts done
fetchNewProducts job done
```

Comment: You are helping me understand more thanks. Nice explanation !

Answer (score 1):

`await` is meant to interrupt the process flow until the `async` method has finished.
`then` however does not interrupt the process flow (meaning the next instructions will be executed) but enables you to run code when the `async` method is finished.

In your example, you cannot achieve what you want when you use `then` because the code is not **waiting** and the return statement is processed and thus returns an empty `List`.

When you add the `await`, you explicitly say: **don't go further until my `Future` is completed**.

```
_loadHotProducts = await HotProductsApiClient().fetchHotProducts(http.Client(), userId);
_loadNewProducts = await NewProductApiClient().fetchNewProducts(http.Client(), userId);
_loadPromotions = await PromotionApiClient().fetchPromotion(http.Client());
_loadLatestSoldItem = await LatestSoldApiClient().fetchProducts(http.Client(), userId);
```

Using `await` directly in the `setState` won't work, since `setState` function isn't `async` and it is not recommended. Just wrap them with an `async` function that will be called in the `setState` method. So the final result should be something like this:

```
Future<List<HotProducts>> _loadHotProducts;
Future<List<NewProducts>> _loadNewProducts;
Future<List<Promotion>> _loadPromotions;
Future<List<LatestSoldItem>> _loadLatestSoldItem;
Future load() async {
  userId = result;
  _loadHotProducts = await HotProductsApiClient().fetchHotProducts(http.Client(), userId);
  _loadNewProducts = await NewProductApiClient().fetchNewProducts(http.Client(), userId);
  _loadPromotions = await PromotionApiClient().fetchPromotion(http.Client());
  _loadLatestSoldItem = await LatestSoldApiClient().fetchProducts(http.Client(), userId);
  }
setState(() {
  load();
});
```

Comment: "await is meant to interrupt the process flow", I think "pause" is a more suitable word and FYI "setState function isn't async" that's because it doesn't `return` a `future`

Answer (score 0):

you could use `await`

```
Future<List<HotProducts>> _loadHotProducts;
Future<List<NewProducts>> _loadNewProducts;
Future<List<Promotion>> _loadPromotions;
Future<List<LatestSoldItem>> await _loadLatestSoldItem;
userId = result;

_loadHotProducts = await HotProductsApiClient().fetchHotProducts(http.Client(), userId);
_loadNewProducts = await NewProductApiClient().fetchNewProducts(http.Client(), userId);
_loadPromotions = await PromotionApiClient().fetchPromotion(http.Client());
_loadLatestSoldItem = await LatestSoldApiClient().fetchProducts(http.Client(), userId);

setState(() {});
```

You will need to make the method async.

Comment: hi, i already try it, i get this error  `Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods.`

Comment: yes you should add the async keyword to ur method
`methodName() async {`